# in react native Hermes engine increases size of app

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-hermes

after enabling Hermes I see the performance increase but the size of the app increase by 1.3Mb
so there is any way to make the size smaller?

Comment: Is this Android or iOS?

Comment: for now its IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, using Hermes will necessarily make the app bigger.

This is because React Native iOS will by default use the platform's built-in JavaScript interpreter instead of bundling its own. When you use Hermes, you are adding a JSVM to the app where there wasn't one before, increasing the size.

Android does not have a platform JSVM, so React Native always ships one. When you enable Hermes on Android, you are replacing one JSVM with another, so the size difference is smaller and likely negative.